# How can setup routing for Power BI via firewall in Azure

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

In this scenario requirement is connecting to azure synapse and data factory which in public end point.
Public end point should be accessed through firewall in virtual network

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the relevant [Microsoft Azure Datacenter IP's](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) to connect through to the VNET. The relevant ranges will depend on your PowerBI instance's home location. If you log in to PowerBI online, click the ? and select "About PowerBI" you will get the box below and you can tell from the "Your data is stored in" attribute.

[image: you need to add the correct ranges to your VNETs firewall.]

It is updated weekly but changes affecting the PowerBI don't seem to occur often, in fact, in the last 6 months this has been stable for us. We struggled to find the right range, so we set up a simple PowerBI report that connects to an open Azure storage account with logging enabled and then refreshed the report from PowerBI service and looked in the storage account's firewall logs to see the IP the requests are originating from. This helped us to narrow down the IP's we needed to white list.

Comment: Did you setup, your firewall between virtual network and public end point as a VM appliance?

Comment: No, we were accessing Azure resources that were connected via service endpoints so we opened the relevant range on the services we were connecting to. I assume an appliance should work too.

Comment: Sounds great. But user policies sucks. Can you recommend anything rather than Azure documentation